# Drawing reciprocal lattice structures

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, lattice-model

I am currently trying to understand why and how reciprocal lattice relates to the diffraction plane, so I did some research on Wiki about reciprocal lattice, but I seem to be stuck as I would like to be able to draw a diagram of a reciprocal lattice but can't seem to visualize how. I am okay with the Miller indices and primitive vectors, but I am not entirely sure if I am supposed to use these in a 2d space or 3d space to draw for the reciprocal lattice.

What more confusing is the BCC lattice are 3d and I am not sure if I am supposed to drawing 2d first then use the vectors and draw the reciprocal, it seems very muddling and would just like a place to start. Could anyone offer any advice?

Comment: How do you draw a real-space lattice structure? Take a real-space Bravais lattice. Construct the reciprocal lattice from the standard formulas - this will also be a Bravais lattice by definition. Figure out how to draw the reciprocal space Bravais lattice with appropriate artistic touches (I'm terrible at that part). Note that the reciprocal lattice of bcc is an fcc lattice (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have known,one constructs an ewald sphere in reciprocal lattice with its radius being 1/(incident wavelength).The points which lie on the sphere correspond to the different planes which diffract in the crystal' real space.